# Flask Restful Parse POST data

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, flask, flask-restful

I am sending a POST request with `cURL` to `Flask Restful API` as:

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' -d @trace.csv http://localhost:5000/upload`

I am not able to read this data from this request or I don't know how to read the data. Below is my implementation of the `API`:

```
class ForBetaAndUpload(Resource):
    def post(self, kind='quotes'):    
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('file')
        args = parser.parse_args()['file']
        print(args) #Prints: Null

api.add_resource(ForBetaAndUpload, '/upload', endpoint='upload')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

How can I read the csv file data that I'm sending with `cURL`. I'll very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by default `parser.add_argument` [will use GET params](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/reqparse.html#argument-locations) (`location='args'`). To get POST data, you need to specify `location='form'` in its arguments:

```
parser.add_argument('file', location='form')
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.